# Mongo Geo aggregate framework get distance between two points

Tags: mongodb

According to this

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/geoNear/

the aggregate framework can return the distance of a point from a coordinate,

is there way I can feed and get the distance between two points or a point to polygon?  or would it be more efficient to do this in my C# code?

Example:
I have the following address created

```
"LocationName" : "Pot of Gold",
  "Address" : {
    "Street" : "13305 104TH ST",
    "City" : "PLEASANT PRAIRIE",
    "StateProvince" : "WI",
    "PostCode" : "",
    "County" : "us",
    "Country" : "United States of America",
    "CountryCode" : "Kenosha County",
        "Gps" : {
          "bbox" : [-180.0, -90.0, 180.0, 90.0],
          "geometry" : {
              "type" : "Point",
              "coordinates" : [-87.917057, 42.524231]
     },
      "type" : "Feature"
}
```

We get a gps location of -86.9439485, 42.58495849

I would like to user the gps location and find out far away that spot is from the Pot of gold location.

Comment: By 'feed' do you mean the points are not being stored in mongodb?

Comment: sorry I assumed that, yes they are two points already stored in the db.

Comment: Include a sample document in your question and explain what you want to match from it.